# Animation not working after removing items from card layout in sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

We have define a container having card layout.

```
Ext.define('RistaSupport.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'mainview',
    itemId: 'mainView',
    requires: [],
    config: {
        autoDestroy:true,
        layout: {
            type: 'card',
            animation: {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'}
        },
        margin: '0 auto',
        maxWidth: '30em',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'loginview',
                'itemId':'loginView'
            },

            {
                xtype: 'registrationview',
                itemId:'registrationView'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'businessregistrationlist'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

When we try to set active item in the container, everything works fine with animation etc. But if we remove items from the container and set active item, animation is not happening.

**Works:**

```
this.getMainView().setActiveItem({xtype: 'businessregistrationlist'});
```

**Doesn't work**

```
this.getMainView().removeAll(true);
this.getMainView().setActiveItem({xtype: 'businessregistrationlist'});
```

Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: I think this is happening because the animation is attached with the child views during initialize. So try with `animateActiveItem` instead of `setActiveItem`.

Comment: animateActiveItem is not working also..

Comment: Have you added the animation parameter in it?

Comment: I added  {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'} as second parameter.

Comment: Try setting the active item after a small delay with setTimeout(), like 100ms

Comment: Setting the active item after delay is not working..